# Firebase auth state persists on client, but not on hard refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-security, isomorphic-javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm building an isomorphic React app that uses Express to handle server requests.

When running the bundled React app on the client side, my Firebase login flow works nicely:

- I login using Firebase's email/password option
- After authentication, `ref.getAuth()` successfully returns the user's auth object
- Subsequent calls to `ref.getAuth()` while navigating through my app client-side (via react-router) also return a successful auth object.

However, hard refreshes (which would come from the server) don't persist, even after a successful login on the client. Using the same React components in a server context, `ref.getAuth()` returns null.

Am I missing a step to make this work on the server in the same manner it works on the client (with the use case being a hard-refresh of the site)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're connecting to Firebase on the server as part of your isomorphic/universal rendering (which I assume you are), Firebase has no way of knowing which user initiated the request to your server that then subsequently issued the request to Firebase—on the client, the user's cookies can be sent along to Firebase, but it's *your server*, not the client, that's initiating the request on the server, and so is not associated with any given user.

My first thought was, in order to send authentication from the server, you'll need to have some sort of login on your own server; once you verify (with Firebase or otherwise) that the user is who they say they are, you can [generate a token](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html) that you can save (securely) in the user's session and also send back to the client. Then, on the client, *and* on *each* server request, just before rendering your React application with `React.render*`, you would call `authWithCustomToken()` with that user's token.

The one caveat, however, is that authentication to a Firebase database is global—when you authenticate a Firebase ref (even in Node.js), every single other ref pointing to the same database gets authenticated with those credentials; you can't log in as different users by using separate refs. So, if your React rendering pipeline on the server does any asynchronous operations between when the auth callback is called and the app is rendered (e.g. if you use something like [react-async](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-async) or do other fancy async data loading before rendering), the user that is authenticated against your Firebase might have *changed* by the time you go to render your application. If, however, your rendering pipeline is purely synchronous, you should be able to get away with this strategy (`getAuth()` can help ensure that you have the right auth before you render).

Aside from that, I think the most straightforward solution is the following:

1. Authenticate your users through your own server, creating a [secure token](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html) and passing it back to the client for authentication purposes. Store this token in the user's session so the client can request it and auth with it on the client as necessary. You'll also need to generate your own auth data (the stuff that is normally passed to the callback for `authWithPassword`) and store this in the session as well.
2. For server requests to your Firebase, use one of [the recommended server authentication schemes](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html#section-authenticating-servers):

   > **Using a Firebase app secret:** All authentication methods can accept a Firebase app secret instead of a JWT token. This will grant the server complete read and write access to the entire Firebase database. This access will never expire unless it is revoked via the App Dashboard.
   >
   > **Using a secure JWT with the optional `admin` claim set to `true`:** This method will grant a server complete read and write access to the entire Firebase database. This token will expire normally, so it is important to set the expiration times accordingly.
   >
   > **Using a secure JWT designed to give access to only the pieces of data a server needs to touch:** This method is more complicated, but it is the safest way to authenticate a server as it lets the [Security and Firebase Rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html) prevent the server from doing anything it's not supposed to, even if it becomes compromised in some way.
3. Include server logic to ensure that the current logged in user can only access appropriate data. Since the above methods of authentication will grant access to data the user may or may not have access to, you'll need to take your *own* steps to ensure that users don't get accidental access to things they shouldn't.
4. Pass the auth data that you stored in the session in step one to the React application as a property, instead of relying on things like `ref.getAuth()` to get this data inside your React app (since it won't work on the server), to identify the user in your UI.

Comment: This is an amazing answer — thank you! If I **am** in fact doing some fancy async data fetching (using react-transmit), would this whole thing be a bust?

Comment: @Jon The first solution, with the caveat, might be a bust, because you can't depend on Firebase implementing your security rules correctly, as a second request might come in and re-auth against the database before the async stuff finishes. However, the second solution, where you implement some of the security on your own server (e.g. making sure the user doesn't request a resource it doesn't have access to), should still work.

Comment: Hmm — so by "implement some of the security on my own server", do you mean more or less duplicating my FB security rules on my Express server?

Comment: @Jon You might not need to duplicate them all, but you'd need to ensure any Firebase rules that depend on the value of `auth` are duped.

Comment: Ok, did some more digging—if I want to use FB for my user auth **and** I want to perform that auth server-side, it seems like my options are the following: a) Use a separate server to do the FB auth. b) Use an undocumented (and subject to change) feature of the SDK that allows for multiple connections on a single ref c) Rule out server-side auth as an option. B/c of the single-connection limitation, you could only do the initial auth against FB on a client with JS enabled, but could then store the token and make non-JS fallback requests with the server. @BinaryMuse, does that sound accurate?

Comment: @Jon I think that sounds about right. I'm not 100% sure what you meant by option (a) (would it be a new process per user? maybe could do this with clustering, or with VM contexts...), and option (b) really intrigues me ;) Option (c) sounds similar to the one I outlined in my answer.

Comment: @Jon One thing about option (c) is, if parts of your app needs to know who the user is (e.g. normally you'd use data returned in the auth callback), the server needs to verify this information itself—it can't simply trust the client to say "Yes, I'm logged in, my username is admin." Once it verifies the identity, however, it can be stored in the session and you'd be good to go.

Comment: I think you're right about a) — even a dedicated auth server might not work b/c you'd need the calls to be synchronous anyway, and that could get dicey. For b) apparently you can pass in the context as a second param (`var ref = new Firebase(url, new Firebase.Context());`, which opens a separate socket for each context. I think c) is the cleanest, and the one I'll go with for now.  Thanks a ton for helping me work this out!

Comment: Also thanks for the clarification on c). I think my plan is to grab the token from the auth object returned from client-side login and supply that to the REST endpoints on the server, which should automatically pick up the permissions associated with that user and respond with the right data.